# [unixODBC][Driver Manager] Can't open lib '/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/universal/libclouderaimpalaodbc.dylib' : file not found

Tags: odbc, cloudera, unixodbc

I am trying to get a Cloudera Impala ODBC running on a brand new **M1 Mac**. To do so, I installed MS ODBC 18 via the [official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15) and also followed the [Cloudera ODBC Connector Install Guide](https://downloads.cloudera.com/connectors/impala_odbc_2.6.14.1016/Cloudera-ODBC-Connector-for-Impala-Install-Guide.pdf).

However, when trying to connect, I get following error:

```
[Error: [odbc] Error connecting to the database] {
  odbcErrors: [
    {
      state: '01000',
      code: 0,
      message: "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/universal/libclouderaimpalaodbc.dylib' : file not found"
    }
  ]
}
```

My ODBC installation:

```
myuser@computer ~ % odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.11
DRIVERS............: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /opt/homebrew/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/myuser/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Drivers]
Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala      = Installed
Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive = Installed

[Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala]
Description = Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala
Driver      = /opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/universal/libclouderaimpalaodbc.dylib

[Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive]
Driver = /opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/universal/libclouderahiveodbc.dylib
```

odbc.ini

```
[foobarbinbaz]
Driver=/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/universal/libclouderaimpalaodbc.dylib
HOST=***
PORT=433
AuthMech=3
UseSASL=0
UID=****
PWD=****
SSL=1
TransportMode=2
HTTPPath=clicervice
CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=1
TrustedCerts=/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/universal/cacerts.pem
TSaslTransportBufSize=1000
RowsFetchedPerBlock=10000
SocketTimeout=0
StringColumnLength=32767
UseNativeQuery=0
```

What I checked:

1. If the file `/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/universal/libclouderaimpalaodbc.dylib` actually exists (it does)
2. Interchanging `Driver` in my odbc.ini `Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala` and `/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/universal/libclouderaimpalaodbc.dylib` (in both cases it's gonna search for the path)
3. The file `/Users/myuser/.odbc.ini` is actually a symlink to `/Users/myuser/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini` (but that shouldn't be a problem, right?)
4. Checked the [Known Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/known-issues-in-this-version-of-the-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) article at Microsoft (but I couldn't find my specific problem)
5. `sudo chmod -R a+rw cloudera` inside the `/opt` directory

Comment: Hey! I am facing the exact same issue on an M1 Mac I am trying to set up, has this issue since been resolved for you?

Comment: I'm also having this issue, any updates?

Answer (score 1):

As of v2.6.11 released 2021-03-26, the *Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive* does not include an ARM64 component in its universal binary. I imagine the same for the Impala driver, too.

```
$ file /opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/universal/libclouderahiveodbc.dylib
/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/universal/libclouderahiveodbc.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [i386:Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
- Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386] [x86_64]
/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/universal/libclouderahiveodbc.dylib (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/universal/libclouderahiveodbc.dylib (for architecture x86_64):       Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
$ lipo -archs /opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/universal/libclouderahiveodbc.dylib
i386 x86_64
```

My system:

```
$ sw_vers 
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.5
BuildVersion:   21G72
$ uname -mprsv
Darwin 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Sat Jun 18 17:07:22 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.41~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64 arm
```

This library won't work until Cloudera updates the driver with an ARM64 version.

See also [Hive ODBC driver on m1 Mac](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-ODBC-driver-on-m1-Mac/m-p/341118#M233446).